# Implementing LU factorization with partial pivoting in C using only one matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, matrix-decomposition, programming

I have designed the following C function in order to compute the PA = LU factorization, using only one matrix to store and compute the data:

```
double plupmc(int n, double **c, int *p, double tol) {
  int i, j, k, pivot_ind = 0, temp_ind;
  int ii, jj;
  double pivot, *temp_row;

  for (j = 0; j < n-1; ++j) {

    pivot = 0.;
    for (i = j; i < n; ++i)
      if (fabs(c[i][j]) > fabs(pivot)) {
        pivot = c[i][j];
        pivot_ind = i;
      }

    temp_row = c[j];
    c[j] = c[pivot_ind];
    c[pivot_ind] = temp_row;

    temp_ind  = p[j];
    p[j] = p[pivot_ind];
    p[pivot_ind] = temp_ind;

    for (k = j+1; k < n; ++k) {
      c[k][j] /= c[j][j];
      c[k][k] -= c[k][j]*c[j][k];
    }

  }
  return 0.;
}
```

where n is the order of the matrix, c is a pointer to the matrix and p is a pointer to a vector storing the permutations done when partial pivoting the system. The variable tol is not relevant for now. The program works storing in c both the lower and upper triangular parts of the factorization, where U corresponds to the upper triangular part of c and L corresponds to the strictly lower triangular part of c, adding 1's in the diagonal. For what I have been able to test, the part of the program corresponding to partial pivoting is working properly, however, the algorithm used to compute the entries of the matrix is not giving the expected results, and I cannot see why. For instance, if I try to compute the LU factorization of the matrix

```
1. 2. 3.
4. 5. 6.
7. 8. 9.
```

I get

```
    1.    0.     0.         7. 8. 9.
l : 0.143 1.     0.     u : 0. 2. 1.714*
    0.571 0.214* 1.         0. 0. 5.663*
```

the product of which does not correspond to any permutation of the matrix c. In fact, the wrong entries seem to be the ones marked with a star.

I would appreciate any suggestion to fix this problem.

Comment: How is that loop at the end supposed to achieve elimination? It does not make sense what you are doing there. In particular it looks like the super diagonal entries are not even modified.

Comment: As for the solution, if pivoting is implemented by actually exchanging rows, then after pivoting has been completed (so the pivot is in position $(j,j)$) you go through row $k$ for $k>j$, replace $c_{kj}$ with $c_{kj}/c_{jj}$ (which is now an entry of $L$) , *and* replace $c_{ki}$ with $c_{ki}-(c_{kj}/c_{jj}) c_{ji}$. Here $i$ has to sweep all the way across the row. What you did was only editing the diagonal entry which is just going to produce nonsense.

Comment: That said off the top of my head I am not sure whether subsequent pivoting will move the new entry of $L$ to somewhere it shouldn't be if you implement pivoting in the way you are trying to implement it.

Comment: You are missing a loop. You need three nested loops for a basic implementation of Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting. The arithmetic complexity is $O(n^3)$. You have $O(n^2)$.